# moment().startOf('week') is not the same for locale('en-ca') and locale('zh-cn')

Tags: react-native, momentjs

```
dt: moment()

console.log(moment(dt).locale('en-ca').startOf('week')).format('MMM D')  //returns Jan 28
console.log(moment(dt).locale('zh-cn').startOf('week')).format('MMM D')  //returns Jan 22
```

First console.log returns Jan 28 for locale('en-ca') which is a Sunday
Second console.log returns Jan 22 for locale('zh-cn') which is a Monday

Time is not in sync

Comment: `startOf('week')` gives output locale-aware (for `zh-cn` week starts on Monday, while for `en-ca` week starts on Sunday), use `startOf('isoweek')` if you want _"locale independent"_ results.

Answer (score 1):

As 28 Jan is a Sunday, the first day of the week for `'en-ca'` is Sunday thus you are getting that as 28.
But in `'zh-cn'` system the first day of the week is considered to be Monday thus 6 days before Sunday i.e. 22nd Jan, Monday.

If you want `'zh-cn'` to use Sunday as first day of week you can do this:

```
moment.lang('zh-cn', {
    week : {
        dow : 0 // Sunday is the first day of the week
    }
});
```